# Inputbox fills cells in table

Tags: excel, vba, userform, inputbox

I have a user form with radio option buttons in it. The option buttons are grouped in sets of 2 and there are 10 sets. For each set, when one of the buttons is clicked I have an inputbox pop up. The user is then asked to place information into the input box. The trouble I am having, is then getting this information recorded back into my excel worksheet table. How is this done?

Also, note that I have several other fields in the user form that I am recording data and information into the same excel table.

```
Private Sub OptionButtong21_Click()
 If Step1 = Application.InputBox("what is the issue?") Then Cells(emptyRow, 
 10).Value = Step1.Caption
End Sub
```

Comment: Please post some code and include information about what you've tried so far.

Comment: Added code. See above.

Comment: I've aborted this approach and I am not trying to launch a second user form from within the existing user form. I think that will be better.